# Error after importing layers weights from CSV to Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

No errors when setting weights with data from CSV's but having problems when evaluating the model with the Keras loaded weights.

I know that I can save the weights in a .h5 file but I'm restricted to only work with CSV files.

I've tried calling:
    **keras.backend.clear_session()**
    **keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)**

after setting the weights but before evaluating the model.

Clearing session seemed to work a little better, the error message changed after.

## Model architecture

```
import tensorflow as tf  
from tensorflow import keras  
import numpy as np  
from keras import models  
from keras import layers  
from keras import regularizers  

model = models.Sequential()  
model.add(layers.Embedding(512, 64))  
model.add(layers.Conv1D(64, 5, activation='elu'))  

model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(3))  
model.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation='elu'))  
model.add(layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(32, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001)), input_shape=(None, 32)))  
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))  

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])  

model.summary()
```

## Loading weights

After importing CSV files and reshaped the data into numpy arrays with the shape it had after training the model (in a different notebook)
**L1**: numpy array shape (1, 512, 64)
**L2**: numpy array shape ((5, 64, 64), (64,))
**L3**: numpy array shape (0,)
**L4**: numpy array shape ((3, 64, 32), (32,))
**L5**: numpy array shape ((32, 128), (32, 128), (128,), (32, 128), (32, 128), (128,))
**L6**: numpy array from importing CSV files. Shape ((64, 3), (3,))

```
W = [L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, L6]  

x = 0  
for layer in model.layers:  
    layer.set_weights(W[x])  
    x += 1
```

## Running the model

So far, no error when running the code.
Now I upload the same data that I used for training the model to test if the weights loaded correctly:
**labels2**: vectorized labes (one hot encoded) shape (85261, 3)
**features**: numpy array with shape (85261, 80)

```
keras.backend.clear_session()  
keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0)  

scores = model.evaluate(features, labels2, batch_size=512, verbose=1, steps=None)
```

I expected to get the same results when trained the original model. The data (features, labels) is the same. But can't run evaluate or predict commands.

I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-bb913425426a> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 scores = model.evaluate(features, labels2, batch_size=512, verbose=1, steps=None)
      3 print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size, verbose, sample_weight, steps)
   1111                                          batch_size=batch_size,
   1112                                          verbose=verbose,
-> 1113                                          steps=steps)
   1114 
   1115     def predict(self, x,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.pyc in test_loop(model, f, ins, batch_size, verbose, steps)
    390                 ins_batch[i] = ins_batch[i].toarray()
    391 
--> 392             batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
    393             if isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    394                 if batch_index == 0:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in __call__(self, inputs)
   2713                 return self._legacy_call(inputs)
   2714 
-> 2715             return self._call(inputs)
   2716         else:
   2717             if py_any(is_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc in _call(self, inputs)
   2673             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals, run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   2674         else:
-> 2675             fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
   2676         return fetched[:len(self.outputs)]
   2677 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1437           ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(
   1438               self._session._session, self._handle, args, status,
-> 1439               run_metadata_ptr)
   1440         if run_metadata:
   1441           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.pyc in __exit__(self, type_arg, value_arg, traceback_arg)
    526             None, None,
    527             compat.as_text(c_api.TF_Message(self.status.status)),
--> 528             c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
    529     # Delete the underlying status object from memory otherwise it stays alive
    530     # as there is a reference to status from this from the traceback due to

InvalidArgumentError: indices[192,4] = -1 is not in [0, 512)
     [[{{node embedding_1/embedding_lookup}} = GatherV2[Taxis=DT_INT32, Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_1/embeddings/read, embedding_1/Cast, embedding_1/embedding_lookup/axis)]]
```

If I add **keras.backend.clear_session()** before evaluating the model, I get the folling error message:

```
ValueError: Tensor Tensor("loss/add_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

Comment: Why are you clearing the session? this effectively deletes the TF side of your model.

Comment: I read that it helped in somes cases but was just testing if it could help. I thought that I needed to overwrite something that was blocking the model from running correctly

Comment: Clearing the session is what is probably producing the problem. You don't even need to set the learning phase.